# Create a custom column in SELECT statement for SORTING only and NOT SHOW it on the result in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here's my query:

```
SELECT name, 1 as rank
FROM names
WHERE name LIKE '%abc%'
UNION
SELECT name, 2 as rank
FROM names
WHERE name LIKE '%xyz%'
ORDER BY rank
```

The problem is duplicate rows won't be combined by UNION since they would differ in the rank column. Now, how would I hide the custom column rank but still use it in ORDER BY clause? Thank you.

EDIT:

I'm actually trying to sort by relevance, eg., whole words && exact phrase first, whole words && non-exact second, non-whole && non-exact third, and so on.

Comment: Have you try it `UNION ALL`?? But not sure what you want. Can you show us sample data, current and expected result?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
  
  And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not combining with union, but use a case statement instead.  This avoids your duplicate issue.

```
Select name from
(Select name , 
Case when name like '%abc%' then 1 else 2 end as rank
 From names
Where name like '%and%' or name like '%xyz%' 
Order by rank)
Group By name;
```

It looks like you want to select all names with 'abc' from names and then select names with 'xyz'.

With this query anything with 'abc' is ranked 1 and anything with 'xyz' (but not 'abc') is ranked 2.

In our where clause we only select names with 'abc' or 'xyz'.  The case applies 1 to 'abc' and all other rows ('xyz' only) get 2.  Ordering should work now with no duplication

Comment: I added distinct from the final select instead.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the `union` and subqueries.   Just do:

```
select name
from names
where name like '%abc%' or name like '%xyz%'
order by (case when name like '%abc%' then 1
               when name like '%xyz%' then 2
               else 3
          end);
```

Note:  If you are concerned about duplicates, you can use `select distinct name`.

Comment: But how does this work (sorry for my ignorance). Can you elaborate a bit what does it mean when you tell SQLite to ORDER BY 1 or ORDER BY 2, etc.? I thought ORDER BY can be used only for columns. Thank you.

Comment: @SidGo . . . `ORDER BY` can be used on expressions.  Those values are integers that specify the priorities for ordering.